# If 2 conditions are met then give accurate result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a formula that if 2 conditions are met then it should give accurate result form the data.

Its answer is 0

```
ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(('Stock In by Invoices'!F5:F=E5)*('Stock In by Invoices'!G5:G=F5)*('Stock In by Invoices'!I5:I2001)))
```

Its answer is #N/A

```
=INDEX('Stock In by Invoices'!I5:I,MATCH(1,('Stock In by Invoices'!F5:F=E5)*('Stock In by Invoices'!G5:G=F5),0))
```

bo

Comment: exactly i am using Google sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing I5:I2001 in the first formula to I5:I.

Otherwise it will be hard to diagnose without a shared sample sheet of some sort.

Comment: Its even not working after putting end rows.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dN9MYe-7HuuPXLSg0s-1l_h7rAIXWPVA/view?usp=sharing